# Is there any point to compressing HTML when using GZIP?

Tags: seo, optimization, compression

I was considering using a ruby gem to compress my HTML, but we're already serving gzipped files, and I was wondering if there is any reduction in served file size by doing both HTML compression and GZIP, or if that's totally pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your files will be smaller if you minify them before using gzip.

- Gzip isn't perfect compression.  It doesn't remove remove all the redundancy that minifying does.
- Gzip is lossless compression.   At the very least that means it has to preserve information such as the number of indentations on each line.  It may only take a byte or two for preserving that info, but if you don't remove that noise, it still is "info" to gzip.

To test this I concatenated 95 JavaScript files from one of my projects.  I minified them using `yui-compressor` and zipped both the minified and unminified versions.  The un-minified version is 27% larger compared to the minified version after gzip has been applied to both.

#### Unminified

- 130K - mega.js
- 33K - mega.js.gz

#### Minified

- 90K - mega.min.js
- 26K - mega.min.js.gz